# what should I do if depth of my data increases in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datamodel, column-family

How should I model my data for which the depth is more and it might increase in cassandra.

Even if I add super column family, it would increase just one more level. (May be I am wrong, I am newbie to Cassandra).

Assuming my data :

```
{
Key1 : {key11:{
        key111: {
             key1111:{
                  key11111:value11111,
                  key11112:value11112
                }
             key1112:{
                  key11121:value11121,
                  key11122:value11122
                }

            }
        key112: {
             key1121:{
                  key11211:value11211,
                  key11112:value11112
                }
             key1122:{
                  key11221:value11221,
                  key11122:value11122
                }

            }
        }
    key12:
        {
        key121: {
             key1111:{
                key11111:value11111,
                key11112:value11112
                }
             key1112:{
                key11121:value11121,
                key11122:value11122
                }

            }
        key122: {
             key1121:{
                key11211:value11211,
                key11112:value11112
                }
             key1122:{
                key11221:value11221,
                key11122:value11122
                }

            }
                }
    }
key2: .. . . . .. .
```

Comment: Cassandra modelling cares less about the data and more about how you intend to query it. This needs more info.

Comment: @AndySavage, Are you expecting kind of Queries that my application needs ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out the resources at http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel.  If you're still thinking in supercolumns your sources are badly dated.